# when one dropdown list selected i want to change other dropdown lists unselected

Tags: php, jquery

I want to do like i said on the question.
This i the main part . When i select any options from that select part . i want to make other select blocks' element unselected.

Assume i have more select blocks for search for year, month, day etc.

Can you help e how i can do that.

```
<select id="makale"  size="4"name="formMakale"style="height:7em;width:16em;border:0px;outline:0px;fontsize:16px;padding-left:10px;" >
<?php 
     $authorsQuery = $hb->authors();
foreach($authorsQuery as $v){
   echo '<option value="'.$v->id.'">'.$v->name.'  -  '.count($hb>aticlesbyauthor($v),1000).' yazi</option>';}
?>
</select>
```

for example my other select block is:

if this block was selected before the upper select block, once select block with id `makale` is selected, make the block with id `kategoriSec` unselected if it is selected as i said before.

Thank you.

```
<select id="kategoriSec"  size="4" name="formCat"style="height:7em;width:16em;border:0px;outline:0px;fontsize:16px;padding-left:10px;" >
    <?php 
  $catQuery = $hb->db->get_results("SELECT * FROM category");
        foreach ($catQuery as $v) {
            echo '<option value="'.$v->id.'">'.$v->name.'</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: without an empty option?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery on change event to do this. First check the 2nd select box is empty or not then set the value to null when you select from the first select box.

```
$("#makale").on('change', function(){
    if($('#kategoriSec').val() != ''){
       $('#kategoriSec').val(null);
    }
});
```

visit the below link for an example. this example may help you.

https://jsfiddle.net/skpaul82/87h5y0dm/5/